# How to redefine datetime data by another in Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, gantt-chart

I got this [Pandas Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d3oVn.png) `data`. Inside, in the start column i have date in datetime format. In the duration column i have a timedelta format. What i whanted to do is to get new datetime in the second line, [by doing 0:00+0:20=0:20.

But when i tried to `data["start"][1] = data["start"][0] + data["duration"][0]` i recieve `SettingWithCopyWarning` Error.

Or `data["start"][2] = data["start"][1] + data["duration"][1]`. [But it still works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/la8yI.png). I wonder have can i fix this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) as follows:

```
data.loc[1, "start"] = data.loc[0, "start"] + data.loc[0, "duration"]
```